# Child text nodes not accounted for in xml count() and other functions

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an xml as:

```
<a>
Anna
<b>Tom<b>
</a>
```

So the element `<a>` has two children:

1. `Anna` : literal text node
2. `<b>Tom<b>` : literal node

So I assume that when I write `count(a/*)`, it should give me 2.

But I get 1 instead.

Why is the text node 'Anna' not being considered?

When I use `<xsl:for-each select="a/*">`, similar thing happens, I get only a single iteration.

Any explanations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path `a/*` selects all child elements, not all child nodes. Use `a/node()` to find all child nodes. But you should find three of them, a text node with white space followed by `Anna` followed by white space, the `b` element, and a text node with white space.

Comment: The exception being if the stylesheet has `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` in which case the whitespace-only text node will disappear and you'll get a count of 2 (nl-Anna-nl text node plus `b` element).